# how to find the difference between two vectors?

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
A <- (1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7)
B <- (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to find out the difference between those two vectors which is 7. 
I have used the `setdiff` and `intersect` function but it keeps on forming a vector that has the same elements as A.

```
setdiff(A, B)
```

I tried removing the duplicates from set A first using the unique function which gave me:

```
unique(A) 
A <- (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

However I still can't manage to find the difference between set A and set B. are there other commands I can use which can group the similarities between A and B and give me the difference which is 7?

Comment: `setdiff(A,B)` works fine for me. I think you need to be more explicit about the objects you have, since `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` is not valid R code but simply your pseudocode.

Comment: no it did not work for me it just gave me the same numbers as vector A

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use `intersect`?

Comment: @Mike I don't think you should add the `c` there, since obviously that fails to reproduce the behavior the OP describes...

Comment: Very true, i'll remove it.

Comment: New to editing...apologies for all of them, just re-edited back to the original

Comment: thank you all for your help, setdiff worked for me when removing the c

Comment: @Mike Np, it was good to indent the code, just not to alter it in a way that invalidates the question, that's all. Anyway, looks like OP figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
A <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
setdiff(A,B)

#[1] 7
```